# jquery prompt user to save when click on paging link or close browser

Tags: jquery, gridview, prompt

Bascially I have a gridview with dropdowns. Rules are:
1. prompt users for changes they make in gridview's drowdowns when:
    a)user click on paging link
    b)click other links to navigate away from page
    c)close browser
2. don't prompt user when they click on save button

I found some code here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/WebFormModifedPrompt.aspx
and did some modification:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
        $().ready(function () {
            InitialDictionary = new Array();
            LoadCurrentValues(InitialDictionary);

            function Check() {
                if (!CompareDictionaries(InitialDictionary)) {
                    wind.onbeforeunload = null;
                    return confirm('Form is modified, Do you want to continue');

                }
            }

            $("a").click(Check)
            $(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
                if (!CompareDictionaries(InitialDictionary)) {
                    return "Form is modified, Do you want to continue";

                }
            })
            $('form').submit(function () { window.onbeforeunload = null; })
        })
    </script>
```

I have trouble with this code, When I changed the dropdown and click on the paging link , it first show the pop up for click function, then it fires 2 times pop ups for the beforeunload event. How do I resolve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

A few problems:

1. `wind` is a typo. Should be `window`.
2. The final `})` is unmatched; I think it's a typo too
3. You forgot to include the `document` in `$(document).ready`
4. Don't forget the semicolons
5. Optimization: Use `[]` instead of `new Array()`

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    InitialDictionary = [];
    LoadCurrentValues(InitialDictionary);

    function Check() {
        if (!CompareDictionaries(InitialDictionary)) {
            window.onbeforeunload = null;
            return confirm('Form is modified, Do you want to continue');
        }
    }

    $("a").click(Check);
    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
        if (!CompareDictionaries(InitialDictionary)) {
            return "Form is modified, Do you want to continue";

        }
    })
    $('form').submit(function() {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    })
});
```

Also, I'm assuming that you have a few external functions here. Also, unless `InitialDictionary` is defined elsewhere, be sure to add `var` in front.

Comment: It looks ok. but I notice one very weird problem. For example, the 1st page first row dropdown value is Pink. the other page dropdown value for the first row is something other than Pink, then when I click from other page and click on any other page, it will always using onbeforeunload to prompt save, which I have not changed at all. I checked on the html of the page, no matter which page, the ids for the dropdown is always using the 1st page's drop down ids. How do I resolve that issue?

Comment: Would you be able to post a link to the page?

Comment: How about the definitions for the other functions (`LoadCurrentValues`, `CompareDictionaries`, etc.)?

Comment: the functions are exceeding the charater limit for comments...I will add to answer of my question, and I have hard time pasting the code :(